# Select values from a dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.4

I would like to calculate the difference between two values from within the same column.  Right now I just want the difference between the last value and the first value, however using last(column) returns a null result.  Is there a reason last() would not be returning a value?  Is there a way to pass the position of the values I want as variables; ex: the 10th and the 1st, or the 7th and the 6th?

`Current code`
Using Spark 1.4.0 and Scala 2.11.6

`myDF =` some dataframe with n rows by m columns

`def difference(col: Column): Column = {
    last(col)-first(col)
  }`

`def diffCalcs(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    import hiveContext.implicits._
    dataFrame.agg(
      difference($"Column1"),
      difference($"Column2"),
      difference($"Column3"),
      difference($"Column4")
    )
  }`

When I run `diffCalcs(myDF)` it returns a `null` result.  If I modify `difference` to only have `first(col)`, it does return the first value for the four columns.  However, if I change it to `last(col)`, it returns `null`.  If I call `myDF.show()`, I can see that all of columns have `Double` values on every row, there are no `null` values in any of the columns.

Comment: I pass the column I want to a function that does: `last(col)-first(col)`, but it returns a `null`.  The `first(col)` returns the appropriate, but `last(col)` returns `null`.

Comment: I guess I also want to make clear that none of the values in the column are `null`, they are all doubles.

Comment: Please, post a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added code from the portion that is giving problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Spark 1.5.0, I was able to use the code snippet provided in the question and it worked.  That was what ultimately fixed it.  Just for completeness, I have included the code that I used after updating the Spark version.

```
def difference(col:Column): Column = {
  last(col)-first(col)
}

def diffCalcs(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  import hiveContext.implicits._
  dataFrame.agg(
    difference($"Column1").alias("newColumn1"),
    difference($"Column2").alias("newColumn2"),
    difference($"Column3").alias("newColumn3"),
    difference($"Column4").alias("newColumn4")
  )
}
```